# C# необязательный параметр

Tags: c#

Есть например вот такая функция

```
void Foo (int х = 23) 
{ 
  Console.WriteLine (х);
}
```

который имеет необязательный параметр `x`. Я всегда читал, что для параметров и локальных переменных в функции начисляется память, то есть строится так называемый `stack`  тогда, когда вызывается функция.
Объясните, в таком случае, где хранится значение переменной `x`.

Comment: Мне кажется, что необязательный параметр работает, как статическая переменная. Т.е при первом доступе к классу, переменная размещается в памяти и потом используется.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите, всё просто. На самом деле, необязательные параметры обрабатываются не на уровне *вызываемой* функции, а на уровне *вызывающей*.

Что это означает? А вот что. 
Для объявления

```
void Foo(int х = 23)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(х);
}
```

компилятор **не генерирует** две функции:

```
void Foo(int х)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(х);
}

void Foo() 
{
    int х = 23;
    Console.WriteLine(х);
}
```

Он в реальности генерирует лишь *одну функцию*

```
void Foo(int х)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(х);
}
```

А вот вызов `Foo()` при этом компилятором переписывается так, как будто вы написали `Foo(23)`! Таким образом, константа `23` вставляется в вызывающий код на этапе компиляции. И хранится он там же, где и хранилась бы при явном вызове `Foo(23)`.

---

Отсюда такое следствие. Допустим, ваша функция `Foo` определена в сборке `A`, а сборка `B` вызывает `Foo()`. Затем, вы меняете в исходнике значение по умолчанию с `23` на `0`, и компилируете снова сборку `A`, но не сборку `B`. Поскольку константа `23` «вкомпилирована» в сборку `B`, то при запуске функция `Foo` будет фактически с параметром `x = 23`, а не `0`.

---

Источник информации: [Optional argument corner cases, part three](https://ericlippert.com/2011/05/16/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-three/).

Answer (score 5):

Стек создается не при вызрве функции, а при создании потока исполнения (execution thread). При вызове функции в нем выделяется и инициализируется память под локальные переменные и формальные аргументы (*иногда это делается через регистры, но IL умеет только через стек*).

Стек потока - это область памяти с механизмом доступа. Значением необязательного параметра всегда является констата (значение, вычисляемое при компиляции), поэтому наверняка для CLR она хранится там же, где и остальные константы.

Answer (score 2):

Хочу добавить к ответу цитату из Рихтера clr via c#

При вызове метода извне модуля изменение значения параметров по умолчанию
является потенциально опасным. Вызывающая сторона использует значение
по умолчанию в процессе работы. Если изменить его и не перекомпилировать
код, содержащий вызов, в вызываемый метод будет передано прежнее значение.
В качестве индикатора поведения можно использовать значение по умолчанию
0 или null. В результате исчезает необходимость повторной компиляции кода
вызывающей стороны. Вот пример:

```
// Не делайте так:
private static String MakePath(String filename = "Untitled") {
return String.Format(@"C:\{0}.txt", filename);
}

// Используйте следующее решение:
private static String MakePath(String filename = null) {
// Здесь применяется оператор, поддерживающий
// значение null (??); 
return String.Format(@"C:\{0}.txt", filename ?? "Untitled");
}
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, в каком именно издании это говорится. У меня под рукой книга по 2.0, там такого вроде нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 на
языке C#. 4-е изд. — СПб.: Питер, 2013. — 896 с.: ил. — (Серия «Мастер-класс»)